Projecting $S^1$ to $\mathbb{R}$
I'm reading Tu's "An Introduction to Manifolds", and he has introduced the idea of critical points, where the differential does not have full rank. From the illustration on page 97 Section 8.9, it looks like the projection of the unit circle $\{(x,y) : x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, say by $\pi: (x,y) \mapsto x$ should yield critical points at the antipodes $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ in $S^1.$
But the differential of $\pi$ is $\pi_* = \Big[\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\Big] = [1,0].$ Then it doesn't seem like there are any critical points, since $\pi_*$ has full rank, and is in fact constant, for all $p \in S^1$ and $X_p \in T_pS^1.$ Which is the case?

You should use MathJax also in the title.

Tupben, the differential of $π$
is not what you wrote, because $T_pS^1$
has dimension 1, not 2.
